# Back button with phonegap (and query mobile?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having a problem with an application I am writing in jquery mobile and phonegap. While testing in the browser, I had no problems using the back button (no phonegap js involved). However once I try on a device with the phonegap js it breaks.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load app
2. Visit several pages (linked internally using #)
3. Click the back button or call history.back() from anywhere (using the js console, or by triggering something that calls it)

On the browser (chromium, firefox etc), it goes back one 'page' (to the previous # link whatever it was). This is the preferred behaviour.

On the device (iPhone 4, iPhone simulator, Android 2.2 (device), Android 3.2 (device)), it goes to the first/landing page (the first 'page' in the index.html file).

I suspect that the problem is with phonegap. Is there a way to revert to the preferred behaviour or the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a space in the data url I was using. It seems that the desktop browsers can handle a space properly, however the mobile browsers convert the space into a `%20%` character. jQuery mobile attempts to use a space, but the browser only remembers the altered character.

**EDIT:**
The jqm page has a data-url attribute that allows you to store multiple pages inside one html document.

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-url="page-one"> ... </div>
<div data-role="page" data-url="page two"> ... </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first pages can be loaded in a few ways...

In a document

```
<a href="#page-one">
```

or through javascript

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page-one");
```

The problem I had was with the page with the data-url `page two`. On the desktop browsers the space was maintained, and the customized history control built into jqm continued to function as expected. but on the mobile browsers, the space turned into an escaped space, which the jqm history control did not recognize or track.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you explain what you mean here in more detail? I don't have spaces... what data url? I dont think im using one in this case.

Comment: @SpiRail I updated the question a week or 2 ago - I don't recall if updating a question sends out a notification to to people who have commented on it. In any case, does my edited question provide you with enough extra information?

Comment: Hi, sorry i never got back to you. I not using the back button anymore. Maybe if i need it again, ill take a look here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use jQuery Mobile's ["Back" button link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/#/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-links.html) attribute? I've used it lightly and it works (used on Android only so far). Are you trying to override the (Android only) [backbutton event](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_events_events.md.html)? Not recommended, for what you want, and not possible on iPhone etc anyway.

Comment: I use `<li><a href="back" href="#somepage">Back</a></li>` in a few places (somepage is _not_ the page it goes back to). It works fine in the browser, but not in phonegap. I also call history.back() in a few places. It works fine in a web browser, but not in phonegap.

Comment: That first href in my comment should be a `data-rel="back"`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hmm. Well, the version of jQuery Mobile you are using might be related - history and nav were problematic at one time.

Comment: I am using the latest version of jquery and jquery mobile. Also, I still suspect the problem lies elsewhere, as the problem doesn't exist in the browser, just in phonegap.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.0.0.js has not.
// When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to call Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
}
```

make sure that in androidmenifest.xml file must contain android:targetSdkVersion greater than android:minSdkVersion

Comment: This looks to be a near direct copy/paste out of the docs, which doesn't really work with jQuery Mobile. It also does nothing to address the actual question.