# iphone - Back button in an app without view controller

Tags: iphone, navigation

I'm completely new to iphone apps. I'm creating an iphone app that is designed in HTML and jquery with phonegap. I want to include a back button on the top like the default one in the iphone. I searched on net but all i found, required view controllers.I don't have multiple views so how can i include a back button on my app. Step by step explanation would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344735/back-button-with-phonegap-and-query-mobile and http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8643474cea395abd/f43a47d10752acaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you include a "back" button if you don't have multiple views? What exactly will you navigate "back" to?

"The net" is correct, you need a `UINavigationController` to house a "back" button which would pop a view to the previous view.

Other than a UINavigationController, you could use a UIToolbar and set a button to the left hand corner and give it the title of "Back" to simulate the native appearance — but this would be misleading and pointless.

I don't use PhoneGap, but I am sure there is a way to simulate a NavigationController and manually place a button there. I'm also sure it won't be shaped like a back button either (with the pointy end).

> `javascript:history.go(-1)`

Comment: I have multiple html pages. The app starts with a login screen, after the user logs in, it navigates to next page and further just like a web application. so i need a back button to navigate from one screen to another. if i need UINavigationController, where do i define it?

Comment: Could you not just use `javascript:history.go(-1)`? Or just manually define the page you want to navigate back to? `<a href="previous.htm">Back</a>`

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController is a native control which is in iOS frameworks. As you are using HTML, jQueryMobile and phonegap you should not be looking at those controls. You should totally work in your HTML pages and CSS for that purpose.

The below page contains that back button in jquery mobile. You should be implementing this in your html page.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html